# Can dues and subscriptions expenses be deducted 100% to calculate taxable income in an LLC company?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, accounting, limited-liability-company

I'm using Quickbooks Online, "Dues & Subscriptions" is one of the expense accounts we have. I would like to know if this expense can be deducted 100% for calculating my taxable income. Our company is an LLC in WA state. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IRS Publication 529](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p529.pdf) is the go-to document.  Without being a tax professional, I'd say if the dues and subscriptions help you in the running of your business, then they're deductible.

You're on your own if you take my advice (or don't). ;)